# Recursion: function doesn't recover value from stack

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

I'm using a recursive method to deal with some matrixes. The problem is: when the recursion backs, the value of this matrix are not recovered from stack (the value before and after return are the same).

I try to do a looooot of things, but nothing solve it. By the way, I already tried to compare step by step my program with others (elaborate from friends  and whick works) and until recursion, both programs are equal. After recursion backs, only my matrix are wrong...

Here's a piece of my code:

```
    public static Integer [][] Complement(Integer[][] M){

    if (OneRowNotEmpty(M)) {  // just one row of matrix are different then 0s
      return changeSignalLine(M);
    }

    else {
      int row = DefineLineToErase(M);
      matrix = Complement(zeraLinha(row, M);  // recursion
      dosomething();

    }

    /* make some stuffs, but at this point my M are wrong*/

    return finalMatrix;  // just for illustrate. this matrix are built in lines after recursion
    }
```

It's easier with an example:
In level "A", my matrix are:

> ```
>     [ 00  00]   (matrix on level "A" of recursion)
> M = [ 11  10]
>     [ 11  01]
> ```

Let's assume that my erase row are the second, so:

> ```
>     [ 00  00]   (matrix on level "B" of recursion)
> M = [ 00  00]
>     [ 11  01]
> ```

At this point, on level "B", the function OneRowNotEmpty(M) is true, so it returns the following matrix:

> ```
>     [ 00  00]   (til' here, everything is fine)
> M = [ 00  00]
>     [-11 -01]
> ```

At this point, recursion must return to matrix M on level "A" and keep computing (doSomething()), but it returns to matrix M on level "B" and keep computing (doSomething()). The problem is: this computing occurs with the **wrong** matrix.

It's like the return statement of recursion doens't exist. I can't understand that.

Any thoughts? It's a hard problem to explain, but I tried. Any question, ask me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post Code that compiles?

Comment: http://www.codeshare.io/OUa2M (comments in portuguese. the error occurs after function deMorgan() - in my example, deMorgan() is equivalent to changeSignal(). you can put a break point in that line).

Comment: The recursion works as expected. You need to keep track of the depth if you want some computations only on the entry level.

Comment: can you give an example, please? pseudo code... i already tried to do a lot of things without sucess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

1. Split your function into calling a recursive function and compute on the outcome of  that.

Like so

```
 Integer [][] complement ( Integer[][] m ){
     Integer[][] recurResult = recursiveComplement ( m );
     // recursion has finished
     return doSomething ( recurResult );
 }

 Integer[][] recursiveComplement( Integer[][] m ){
     if( endCondition(m) ) return m; // Checks if Recursion shall be ended.
     Integer[][] levelM = doComplementTransform(m);
     return recursiveComplement( levelM );
 }
```

In recursiveComplement goes the recursion part.

2. Add a depth parameter which you increase in each self- call ( compute ( M, depth +1) ) . If depth is 0 after the call, you are on entry level again.

Comment: don't know if understand right. here's the problematic piece of my code: http://www.codeshare.io/OUa2M. when recursion backs and PC moves to line 15, F isn't the same that are called in line 14. i can't figure out how to keep F intact before P and N be called (I already tried to make a copy of F and use this copy in line 15, but it only works for the first level of recursion)... thanks a lot for your patience! :)

Comment: That is the expected behavior. You tell F to be the result of the next recursion level. What did you expect? And as a sidenote, you return nothing in case status is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally solve it. I just put a depth variable to control recursion and with some modifications in my algorithm, it works.